# Connecting native app for iOS 7.0 to web server and making http requests

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am building a native app for IOS 7.0 (in Objective C).
The app requires users to register / login / send present location to server/ fetching requests from server ...
I mean how can I use Objective C (built in support) to talk to server.

By the way
I know php and node.js. Is there any reason to prefer one over another for my app.
My app has to keep the track of user present location and send it constantly to server. (probably use ajax for that). Also, it has to listen for certain actions of user. So, is there any reason to prefer php over node.js regarding scalability.

Comment: Google. Read docs. Look at parse.com. The server architecture doesn't affect the app really.

Comment: OK, I was not aware about built in support by Objective C provided for this. And I am quite a beginner and google was just showing some third party libraries for this ... So, I asked it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dude try google. Anyways, I hope this will reduce your google time

```
       NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:self.serverURL];


        NSMutableURLRequest *requst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120];

        NSLog(@"request %@ url: %@",requst,self.serviceURL);
        //-->data that needs to be posted to the server...
        NSString* postDataString  = [self preparePostData:dict];


        [requst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [requst setHTTPBody:[postDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requst setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [requst setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        MyAppDelegate *sharedInstance = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requst queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *respone, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
// Code to handle request data
}
```